Python xlwings slow Execution when scanning Excel Sheet
I'm a beginner at Python.
This code is for scanning Excel cells by range using xlwings however the process is very slow.
I strictly need to use xlwings since it can retain my images and shapes unlike openpyxl.
Can somebody give me a faster codes to do this?
for row in range(1, 200):  # Adjust the range as needed 
    for col in range(1, 50):  # Adjust the range as needed
        cell_value = workSheet.range((row, col)).value
        workSheet.range((row, col+5)).value = "※ " + cell_value

I try using Range but I think there is a better way that I don't know of right now.

Welcome to SO! Please do not post image of your code. Post your code as text.

You can use only one for loop to make your code work fast. You need to adjust the values of row and col accordingly in your code.

Have you considered using openpyxl? Also, can you explain what you're trying to achieve?

Xlwings is inherently slower than Openpyxl as it has to open Excel etc but certainly reducing the number of loops might help. 
You can loop a range of cells and access the individual cell directly
for cell in ws.range('A2:A30'):
    print(cell.value)


or the current 'used range' in the sheet
for cell in ws.range(ws.used_range):
    print(cell.value)

You may also find the code execution faster if you set the Excel app visibility to False
e.g.
import xlwings as xw
with xw.App(visible=False) as app:  # <-- Set visible to False
    wb = xw.Book('Book1.xlsx')
    ws = wb.sheets('Sheet1')

    for cell in ws.range(ws.used_range):
        print(cell.value)

